# Ayuda asignacion valor en HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Estimados tengo un problema, tengo el siguiente codigo**

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">                           
<div class="form-group">
<span class="help-block">Equipo:</span>
<select class="form-control select" style="width : 300px;"  name="equipo" id="equipo" onchange="cargavalor(this.value);">
<option value=""> </option>
<?php  
$sql="select nombre from script_venta";
$stmt=$db->query($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
$row['nombre'] = ucwords(strtolower(utf8_encode( $row['nombre'] ))); 
$value = str_replace(' ', '_', $row['nombre']);
$options ='<OPTION VALUE="'.$value.'">'.$row['nombre'].'</OPTION>'; 
echo $options;
}   
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 " id="valor_equipo" >                           
<div class="form-group">
<span class="help-block">Valor Equipo:</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width : 300px;" id="monto_equipo" aria-describedby="" readonly > 
</div>
</div>
```

**al seleccionar un equipo debería ejecutar el la siguiente función**

```
function cargavalor(val){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'script_cargavalor.php',
data: 'equipo='+val,
success: function(resp1){
$('#monto_equipo').val(resp1);
}
});
}
```

**codigo de script_cargavalor.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('./includes/config.php');


$nombre =  $_POST["equipo"];
$sql=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM script_venta WHERE Nombre = "'.$nombre.'"');
$sql->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $tipo= $row["valor_equipo_venta"];
}
echo $tipo;
?>
```

pero por algún motivo al seleccionar algún registro no carga nada y deja sin poder seleccionar algún otro registro en el select "equipo"

es mi primer post y llevo poco en desarrollo web y la pagina ya estaba creada con una modalidad bastante antigua, quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Puedes utilizar jQuery en el Combobox, con la función **onChange** y llamar directamente al Ajax sin necesidad de la función.

Comment: me podrias guiar con algun ejemplo. podria realizar la consulta sql en la misma linea?, quizas no explique bien lo que quiero realizar. Cuando el usuario me seleccione un equipo esto deberia detonar la busqueda del valor del equipo en una BD, y cargarlo en el INPUT "monto_equipo"

Comment: Tu código necesita ser mejorado en varios aspectos, pero lo primero es verificar que no haya errores en el servidor o en el cliente. Intentar pasar el parámetro `data` de Ajax así: **`data: {equipo: val},`** y también activa la consola de Javascript y dinos si muestra algún error, pues dices que los `select` se bloquean.

Comment: Si con respecto a que el select se bloqueaba ya lo resolví, sin querer me falto el cierre de un Div el cual ocacionaba el problema, una pregunta A. Cedano , la manera de recibir los datos en el archivo **script_cargavalor.php**  es la misma, es decir,  `$nombre =  $_POST["equipo"]; ` , muchas gracias